# Swift reduce tuple array custom data model

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter, tuples, reduce

I am attempting to reduce "y" value components for each similar "x" value in this CustomDataModel array, and return a CustomDataModel array (or simply an array of tuples [(Double, Double)].

My knowledge of Swift is rudimentary at best and the attempt to use a chaining function as follows reduces across the entire array and not per "x" value. I'm not sure how I can limit the reduce function to only the like values.

```
let reducedArray = yValues.filter( {$0.x == $0.x}).map({$0.y}).reduce(0, +)
```

the above function reduces all y values not per x.
Below is a the model and some dummy data:

```
struct CustomDataModel {
    var x : Double
    var y : Double
}

let yValues: [CustomDataModel] = [
CustomDataModel(x: 0.0, y: 10.0),
CustomDataModel(x: 1.0, y: 5.0),
CustomDataModel(x: 1.0, y: 12.5),
CustomDataModel(x: 1.0, y: 14.5),
CustomDataModel(x: 1.0, y: 18.45),
CustomDataModel(x: 5.0, y: 11.4),
CustomDataModel(x: 5.0, y: 9.4),
CustomDataModel(x: 5.0, y: 18.4),
CustomDataModel(x: 5.0, y: 5.0),
CustomDataModel(x: 9.0, y: 7.6),
CustomDataModel(x: 9.0, y: 13.5),
CustomDataModel(x: 9.0, y: 18.5),
CustomDataModel(x: 9.0, y: 17.6),
CustomDataModel(x: 9.0, y: 14.3),
CustomDataModel(x: 14.0, y: 19.6),
CustomDataModel(x: 14.0, y: 17.8),
CustomDataModel(x: 14.0, y: 20.1),
CustomDataModel(x: 14.0, y: 21.5),
CustomDataModel(x: 14.0, y: 23.4),
]
```

Ideally the output I would have would look like this:

```
print(reducedArray)
//[(0.0, 10.0), (1.0, 50.45), (5.0, 44.2), (9.0, 71.5), (14.0, 102.4)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the `yValues` array by `x` into a `Dictionary`. And map the values to `y` and then perform `reduce`. Here's how:

```
let reducedArray = Dictionary(grouping: yValues, by: \.x).mapValues({ $0.map(\.y).reduce(0, +) })
print(reducedArray)
```

Update: If you require the result to be in `[(Double, Double)]` format you can map the above result to tuples.

Comment: Thanks Frankenstein for the quick answer. Producing the dictionary can work, as I can sort it, but is there anyway to maintain the tuple structure [(double, double)] as the application requires I am able to iterate over the index.

Comment: I think I figured it out doing the following: `let mapped = reducedArray.map{$0}.sorted(by: <)`